# Passing arrays from HTML forms to PHP and then to WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass arrays from a form to php, and everything works fine until in php file it reaches Foreach loop, inside it it runs only one time (on all other loop cycles var_dump gives NULL).

HTML:

```
 <div id="dynamicInput">
                 <div class="project">
                    <span>Project images</span> <input id="pr_img" multiple type='file' name='my_file_upload0[]'></br>
                      <input id="pr_name" type='text' placeholder='Project name' name='pname[]'> 
                      <textarea id="pr_desc"  cols="40" rows="8" placeholder='Project description' name='pdescr[]'></textarea>
                </div>


            <script>
            var counter = 1;
            var limit = 99;
            function addInput(divName){
                 if (counter == limit)  {
                      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
                 }
                 else {
                      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                      newdiv.className = "project";
                      newdiv.innerHTML = " <span>Project images</span> <input multiple id='pr_img' type='file' name='my_file_upload" + counter + "[]'></br><input id='pr_name' type='text' placeholder='Project name' name='pname[]'> <textarea  cols='40' rows='8' type='text' id='pr_desc' placeholder='Project description' name='pdescr[]'></textarea>";
                      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                      counter++;
                 }
            }
        </script>

            </div>
```

PHP:

```
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );


        $combo = array_combine($_POST[pname], $_POST[pdescr]);

        $countt=0;

        foreach ($combo as $nam => $descri) {

                     $projectid =wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_title'     => $nam,
        'post_type'      => 'Projects',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status'    => 'closed',
        'post_content'   => $descri,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_author'    => $userrid,
        'menu_order'     => 0,

    ) );  
/*---------------------This is the place where it doesnt work------------*/ 

               $files = $_FILES["my_file_upload".$countt.""];
                  ++$countt;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/             
                 foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {   
                            if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
                                $file = array( 
                                    'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                                    'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
                                    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
                                    'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                                    'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                                ); 
                                $_FILES = array ("my_image_upload" => $file); 
                        //var_dump($_FILES);
                                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {              
                                   // $newupload = my_handle_attachment($file,$post_id); 
                          $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, 0);


                                }

                            } 
                            unset($files);
                        } 

                    add_post_meta( $projectid, 'project_pics',  $attach_id, true );
                  if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
                    echo "Error while uploading images";
                  } else {


                  }
```

}

EDIT: $_FILES array content:

```
 ["my_file_upload0"]=>
  array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "bg.bmp"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "bg.png"
}
["type"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "image/bmp"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
}
["tmp_name"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(38) "/customers/c/e/b/********/phpO2lni7"
  [1]=>
  string(38) "/customers/c/e/b/********/phpcIObqF"
}
["error"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(0)
}
["size"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(64)
  [1]=>
  int(10946)
  }
}
["my_file_upload1"]=>
 array(5) {
 ["name"]=>
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "job-icon.png"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "nova.png"
}
["type"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
}
["tmp_name"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(38) "/customers/c/e/b/********/phpZKskyd"
  [1]=>
  string(38) "/customers/c/e/b/********/phpbMlgIL"
}
["error"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(0)
}
["size"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(15213)
  [1]=>
  int(10906)
}
```

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Put solutions in answers, not in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the contents of `$_FILES`. My guess is you'll see only `my_file_upload0`, where as in your loop you're trying to loop through `my_file_upload0`, `my_file_upload1`, `my_file_upload2` etc.

You need to loop through `$_FILES['my_file_upload0']` itself, as this should be an array containing all of the files selected in the file input on your form.

```
   foreach($_FILES['my_file_upload0'] as $key => $files) {
      // Code
   }
```

Edit - I'd actually recommend changing the name of `my_file_upload0` to just `my_file_upload` - for clarity.

Second Edit -I've replicated what you're doing with the supplied array here - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j88g-i2ci This goes through the `for` loop twice without issue.

Comment: +1 on the edit, make all the file inputs `my_file_upload[]`, then `foreach($_FILES['my_file_upload'] as $key => $files) { ...` should work

Comment: You both are right, but I think this is not the case. In the html form I have js  script to create as much new elements as users wants(max 99, every element will be a new custom post in Wordpress), so to differentiate between them, I use my_file_upload**0**, my_file_upload**1** and so on. Inside $_FILES everything is fine, I can see all the pictures I've uploaded, but primary problem remains. Foreach loops it only one time

Comment: @AndriusMotuzas Could you post an example of the contents of $_FILES in your original question?

Comment: @thebluefox, have a look. can it be that I'm overwriting $_FILES array, because I'm mentioning it in the loop 2 times?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so considering you're looping through `$files` and not `$_FILES`

Comment: @thebluefox ok finaly got it. I think I was overeriting the $_FILES array, because after changing name it started to work, and there was some logical errors. Thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Probably $_FILES array was overwrited, because it was mentioned two times. After changing name it started to work, plus there was some logical errors.